# could not sending data to server using on success function in android studio

Tags: android

i am trying to send data from sqlite database to server but i am getting the error on the on failure function that cannot connect to  the internet.while my internet is connected.

```
public void syncSQLiteMySQLDB(){

    //Create AsycHttpClient object
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList =  controller.getAllUsers();
    if(userList.size()!=0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"synchingi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (controller.dbSyncCount() != 0) {
            prgDialog.show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"posting",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            params.put("usersJSON", controller.composeJSONfromSQLite());
            client.post("http://10.0.2.2/insertuser.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

               @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int status, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"on success function",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    System.out.println(response);
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    try {
                        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                        System.out.println(arr.length());
                        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                            System.out.println(obj.get("id"));
                            System.out.println(obj.get("status"));
                            controller.updateSyncStatus(obj.get("id").toString(), obj.get("status").toString());
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DB Sync completed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] content, Throwable error) {
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    if (statusCode == 404) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (statusCode == 500) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

            });

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SQLite and Remote MySQL DBs are in Sync!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data in SQLite DB, please do enter User name to perform Sync action", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: `sending data to server using on success function` ? One does not send data with that function.